# outsourcing code

Tags: objective-c

My iPhone game has a lot of **recurring code** (move pictures, add score), that makes it too big when repeating the same code on each button click.

***this is ViewController.m***

interface and implementation between Viewcontroller.h and ViewController.m is correct - workes well

```
- (IBAction)button_xx_pressed:(id)sender
{

    //trying to call the outsourced code
    [self this_is_a_test];  

}
```

so I tried to make outsourced recurring code. I don't need method or functions that gives a result back or something. Just do some action like NSLog output...(just a test). Or in the original version - move pictures, add score and other stuff.

***this is Outsourcing.h***

```
#import "Outsourcing.m"

@end
```

***this is Outsourcing.m***

```
#import "Outsourcing.h"


- (void)this_is_a_test {

    int test_variable = 999;

    NSLog(@"Give me a test output: = %i", test_variable);

}


@end
```

this would shrink the size of my game more than 80% (very important). I have thousands of recurring programming lines and at the moment, I don't know how to handle it.

*actual error messages:*

Outsourcing.h => missing context for method declaration

Outsourcing.m => missing context for method declaration
              => @end must appear in Objective-C context

Anyone any hints for me? Thank you very much... The rest of my game is ok... everything would run without issues. I'm very glad that I got it running (but the game size is a problem).
1 or 2 months ago, I never used xcode before. I just had some experience in VBA. And what I want is similar to.

=> Call this_is_a_test

=> Private Sub this_is_a_test()

But it seems I'm too stupid :-(

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface Outsourcing : NSObject

- (void)this_is_a_test;

@end
```

---

```
#import "Outsourcing.h"

@implementation
- (void)this_is_a_test {

    int test_variable = 999;

    NSLog(@"Give me a test output: = %d", test_variable);
}
@end
```

and you call it like this in your ViewController:

```
#import "Outsourcing.h"

...

- (IBAction)button_xx_pressed:(id)sender
{
    Outsourcing *outsourcing = [[[Outsourcing alloc] init] autorelease];

    //trying to call the outsourced code
    [outsourcing this_is_a_test];  
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is what I mean.... I see a lot of hopefully code... but they don't work within my programm.

Comment: solved this way.....

- (IBAction)this_is_a_test:(id)sender

and call it this way....
[self this_is_a_test:0];

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

```
@interface Outsourcing : NSObject
```

in your header file (Outsourcing.h). Remove:

```
#import "Outsourcing.m"
```

You import header files, not source files....You are also missing:

```
@implementation Outsourcing
```

In your .m file, just after the import declaration.

Comment: Hi, it would be helpfully if you specify exactly in which file I have to implement which code... thank you. I tried everything with you hints, but there are still error messages....

Comment: Hi, for me the best way is...


***code***
- (IBAction)do_something:(id)sender
{
code
}

***call it***
[self do_something:0];


Both is included in ViewController.m

regards